# How to create a dynamic json body in java

Tags: java, json

I have a data table set up and what I want to do is flick through the table and set the json body based on the table.

My thought process is to get the column names and based off that, if there is a value set, then add this to the body to then send through as a request.

So for example:

```
|colour|food |
|      |pizza|
|red   |     |
```

So when it iterates through the first row, it should create a json body of:

```
"food":"pizza"
```

The above will be sent as a request.

After the request has been done, we move to the second row and the json body for that to pass through as a request will be:

```
"color":"red"
```

So as you can see, we are ignoring missing values in each row and only passing through fields (columns) with values in them.

My question is how to construct that json body in order to do this?

At the moment I manage to iterate through the column names but not sure how to construct that dynamic body. Currently I have:

```
public void testMethod(final Table table) {

    table.getColumnNames().forEach(columnName -> {
        final String value = table.getTableRows().get(0).getCell(columnName);

        postRequest("/test/endpoint", getCurrentHeaders(), SerializationHelper.asString(body));

    });
}
```

I haven't set body, I just thought of setting up the structure and hoping somebody can fill this missing piece of creating the 'body' variable to pass through the expected json body request.

Comment: It's a little difficult to follow what you want (or why), but you probably just need to collect into a `Map<String, V>`.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- The reason I am doing this is because it's an automation test, to check required fields (each column name represents a required field) throws an error if they're missing in a request one by one. I am not good at Mapping (or I should say I will need to learn it). If you can show me an example, I think I will have more of a chance to learn it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On JAVA, to create JSON we (I) usually use the [`org.json`](https://stleary.github.io/JSON-java/) namespace.

First create the object:

```
JSONObject body = new JSONObject();
```

Next fill it with value, for each table row iteration:

```
//this will be to fill the array config
JSONArray rowArray = new JSONArray();

//I don't know what your Table is
//  so this is just a pseudo code to get rows
table.getRows().forEach(row -> {
    table.getColumnNames().forEach(columnName -> {
        final String value = row.getCell(columnName);
        if(!value.equals("")){
            JSONObject thisColumn = new JSONObject();
            thisColumn.put(columnName, value);
            rowArray.put(thisColumn);
        }
    });
});

//now set our array into the JSON body
body.put("config", rowArray);
```

Finally, do the request outside your loop:

```
postRequest("/test/endpoint", getCurrentHeaders(), SerializationHelper.asString(body));
```